# Convert Month wise data into Day wise in a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below in month wise.I want to convert it into day wise.In the dataframe, there are two columns named BP and RE and these values are month wise value.Also there is an another column named 'days_div' it contains the value to divide the BP and RE value.For example,In the month January there is 31 days,suppose in the dataframe month wise  BP and RE value is 28 and corresponding days_div column value is 28,the output dataframe should show BP and RE value as 1 from first of january to 28th of january and remaining 3 days(29th,30th and 31st) should show as 0.sililarly for other months.

input dataframe:

```
Year   Month    Region    Factory    Category    Parameter   UOM   BP      RE   days_div
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA       efficiency   %    25      28         25
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA        Tur FS      MT   23      26         29
2023  February  Delhi        A          QS        UFS         T    27      26         27
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Year   Month      Region    Factory    Category    Parameter   UOM   BP     RE   Date
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         efficiency   %    1     1.12  2023-01-01 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         efficiency   %    1     1.12  2023-01-02 
....  .....     .....       ...        ....        ..........  ...  ...    ....  ..........

2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         efficiency   %     1    1.12  2023-01-25 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         efficiency   %     0      0   2023-01-26 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         efficiency   %     0      0   2023-01-27 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         efficiency   %     0      0   2023-01-28 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         efficiency   %     0      0   2023-01-29 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         efficiency   %     0      0   2023-01-30 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         efficiency   %     0      0   2023-01-31 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         Tur FS       MT 0.793103 0.896552  2023-01-01 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         Tur FS       MT 0.793103 0.896552  2023-01-02 
....  .....     .....       ...        ....        ..........  ...  ...    ....  ..........

2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         Tur FS       MT 0.793103 0.896552  2023-01-25 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         Tur FS       MT 0.793103 0.896552   2023-01-26 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         Tur FS       MT 0.793103 0.896552   2023-01-27 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         Tur FS       MT 0.793103 0.896552   2023-01-28 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         Tur FS       MT 0.793103 0.896552   2023-01-29 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         Tur FS       MT 0               0   2023-01-30 
2023  January   Kerala       A          QA         Tur FS       MT 0               0   2023-01-31 
2023  February  Delhi       A           QS            UFS        T  1.000000  0.962963 2023-02-01 
2023  February  Delhi       A           QS            UFS        T  1.000000  0.962963 2023-02-02 
2023  February  Delhi       A           QS            UFS        T  1.000000  0.962963 2023-02-03 
2023  February  Delhi       A           QS            UFS        T  1.000000  0.962963 2023-02-04 
2023  February  Delhi       A           QS            UFS        T  1.000000 0.962963 2023-02-05 
..   ...      ...     ...     ...      ...         ...  ..       ...       ...       ...        ...
2023  February  Delhi       A           QS            UFS        T  1.000000  0.962963 2023-02-26 
2023  February  Delhi       A           QS            UFS        T  1.000000  0.962963 2023-02-27 
2023  February  Delhi       A           QS            UFS        T  0         0       2023-02-28
```

Here the BP and RE value is divided by days_div column value and show it in day wise from first day of particular year and month till the day mentioned in days_div column and remaining days BP and RE value assigned as zero.In 2023 February month there is 28 days.In leap year , february month has 29 days.There will be change in that case.

Can anyone suggest a solution to achieve this output?

Comment: Is there a `day` column available, I can see there is `Year`, `month`, but no `day` column? If it is than you can just sort the rows by `date` (`year+month+day) and then apply `if/else` condition to check if the `date` is less than `BP` or `RE` and update the value accordingly. Also you should explain a bit more about what exactly are `BP`, `RE` and `days_div` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `Date` column by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and new rows by [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`Series.dt.daysinmonth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.daysinmonth.html) in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Then create counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and add days by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to `Date`s with division `BP,RE` columns by `days_div` in [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) and set `0` by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for compare by [`DataFrame.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) for less or equal:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'] + df['Year'].astype(str), format='%B%Y')

out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Date'].dt.daysinmonth)]
s = out.groupby(level=0).cumcount()

out['Date'] = out['Date'].add(pd.to_timedelta(s, unit='d'))

out[['BP','RE']] = (out[['BP','RE']].div(out['days_div'], axis=0)
                                    .mask(df['days_div'].le(s), 0))

out = out.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print (out)
    Year     Month  Region Factory Category   Parameter UOM   BP        RE  \
0   2023   January  Kerala       A       QA  efficiency   %  1.0  1.120000   
1   2023   January  Kerala       A       QA  efficiency   %  1.0  1.120000   
2   2023   January  Kerala       A       QA  efficiency   %  1.0  1.120000   
3   2023   January  Kerala       A       QA  efficiency   %  1.0  1.120000   
4   2023   January  Kerala       A       QA  efficiency   %  1.0  1.120000   
..   ...       ...     ...     ...      ...         ...  ..  ...       ...   
85  2023  February   Delhi       A       QS         UFS   T  1.0  0.962963   
86  2023  February   Delhi       A       QS         UFS   T  1.0  0.962963   
87  2023  February   Delhi       A       QS         UFS   T  1.0  0.962963   
88  2023  February   Delhi       A       QS         UFS   T  1.0  0.962963   
89  2023  February   Delhi       A       QS         UFS   T  0.0  0.000000   

    days_div       Date  
0         25 2023-01-01  
1         25 2023-01-02  
2         25 2023-01-03  
3         25 2023-01-04  
4         25 2023-01-05  
..       ...        ...  
85        27 2023-02-24  
86        27 2023-02-25  
87        27 2023-02-26  
88        27 2023-02-27  
89        27 2023-02-28  

[90 rows x 11 columns]
```